# wifi services not working in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I just installed ubuntu and fire this command :

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be 

sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_set = 1
```

how to get it back my display?

Comment: question is not related to ruby on rails, you might get answer here https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: thanks 4 ur suggestion don't know about askubuntu.com. I am totally new in this so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do.

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be ant_set = 1
```

i hope it will work ...

Comment: ja, you can ask this question in askubuntu.com

Comment: thanks, its work with diese command ...thank you so much ...u saved my time

Answer (score 0):

In our company we have this issue just in HP laptop and we solve it in 6 step

1- open **software and update** icon from the search field

2- go to **Additional Drivers** go to Realtek Semiconductor.......

3- select the same choice in the picture

[image]

4- run this command: `sudo apt install`

5- run this command: `sudo apt update`

6- restart your computer

And enjoy :)